# fetch full kernel version in kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, version

Kernel defines two macros `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` and `KERNEL_VERSION` that can be used to check the kernel version. However it doesn't allow to check if the version string has `EXTRAVERSION` suffix, for example `4.11.0-rc8`.

I need such check at compilation time. What else can I look at instead above mentioned macros?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read `include/config/kernel.release` as kernel's makefile said:

```
# Read KERNELRELEASE from include/config/kernel.release (if it exists)
KERNELRELEASE = $(shell cat include/config/kernel.release 2> /dev/null)
KERNELVERSION = $(VERSION)$(if $(PATCHLEVEL),.$(PATCHLEVEL)$(if $(SUBLEVEL),.$(SUBLEVEL)))$(EXTRAVERSION)
```

And during the compilation Makefile will export kernel's version infos, maybe you can use it.